# Check if all input field lengths are 7

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are multiple input fields with a common class. I need to check if the length of all those fields are 7.

This is what I tried, however even if the length of all fields are 7, `if (!lengthcheck)` doesn't execute.

```
var lengthcheck = $('.price').filter(function(){
      return !$.trim($(this).val()).length != 7;
}).length;

if(!lengthcheck){
 //go ahead
}
```

Comment: `lengthcheck != 7`?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is because the logic check is reversed. You need to remove the leading `!`:

```
return $.trim($(this).val()).length != 7;
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xqjua72e/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it a little

```
var lengthcheck = $('.price').filter(function(){
      return $.trim($(this).val()).length  == 7;
}).length;

if(!lengthcheck){
 //go ahead
}
```

Comment: FYI the operator should be `!=` as to coerce `lengthcheck` to the required boolean it should return `0` when all fields are valid.

Answer (score 0):

you can also check via simply using the class length

$('.input_class').length